# How to get global data in Onreceive of BroadCast receiver in android

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, global

There was an issue in getting an global data into an BroadCast receiver Class,

and this was my codings,
help me to get into the BroadCast receiver class

```
public class Global extends Application{

String mobileNumber;
public String getMobileNumber() {
    return mobileNumber;
}
public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
    this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
}
```

This was my Receiver Class,

```
public class TextMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

Global global;
Context context;
int count;



String number;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
      global=(Global)context;
      number = global.getMobileNumber();

    Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
    Object[] messages=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] sms=new SmsMessage[messages.length];

    for(int n=0;n<messages.length;n++){
        sms[n]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
    }

    for(SmsMessage msg:sms){
        if(msg.getOriginatingAddress().endsWith(number))
        {
            SMS.updateMessageBox(msg.getOriginatingAddress(),msg.getMessageBody(),context);
        /*SMS.updateMessageBox("\nFrom: "+msg.getOriginatingAddress()+"\n"+
                "Message: "+msg.getMessageBody()+"\n");*/
            /*((SMS) context).delete();*/
        abortBroadcast();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I need to get mobile number from getter setter, but i cant, how to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
global=(Global)context;
```

to Following:

```
global=(Global)context.getApplication();
```

now access, fields of Global Class.

Comment: an error occured, Create method 'getApplication'

Comment: try using context.getApplication() instead

Comment: Yeah , i got it, by using global=(Global)context.getApplicationContext(); thanks jeet..

Comment: change into global=(Global)context.getApplicationContext();

Answer (score 0):

If you need that mobile number across the application you might want to use [sharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and store it there.

Save the mobilenumber like this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(context, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("mobilenumber", value);
editor.commit();
```

And retrieve it like this in your receiver:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
String number = sharedPreferences.getString("mobilenumber", "");
```

Important to know is also that shared preferences are kept stored, even if you leave the application.

Comment: tnx for ur answer, but error occurs near (MODE_PRIVATE) in receiver class.